# Unable to load properties file for a dependency project inside OSGI container

Tags: maven, properties, apache-camel, osgi-bundle, jbossfuse

Please go through the scenario given below

- I have two maven projects **abc-common** and **abc-service**
- **abc-service** has dependency on **abc-common** project.
- **abc-common** is reading from a properties file named `myConfig.properties` as follows:

  ```
  class PropertiesUtil {
     .....
     Properties props = new Properties();
     props.load(PropertiesUtil.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("myConfig.properties"));
     ....
  }
  ```

This works fine, when I test by creating a dummy main method in either of the projects.

But when I deploy this project into an OSGI container (JBOSS Fuse), it is not working. The prime reason is, in OSGI container, `PropertiesUtil.class.getLoader()` is refering to the bundle corresponding to **abc-service** project and I can read any file from that project, but not from **abc-common** project.

So the question is that, how can I change my code such that, It can read properties from class path of **abc-common** project in an OSGI container.

**Note**
I'm deploying my project as a karaf feature which lists both **abc-service** and **abc-common** bundles as dependencies.

Also, I tried different variants like

```
Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("myConfig.properties")
```

and

```
FrameworkUtil.getBundle(PropertiesUtil.class).getEntry("myConfig.properties.")
```

But none of them worked actually

Comment: Do you put the properties file in the etc folder of Fuse?

Comment: @SoucianceEqdamRashti. No. I'm just adding properties file inside project & it is present in `.jar` file.

Comment: I tried adding properties file both in `/etc` folder and fabric profile. Both approach did n't work.

Comment: I guess you could read the location from an environment variable. When you run it from intellij it refers to the file inside the project. When you run it in the container it refers to the one in the etc folder. In Camel you can write location=file:${karaf.home}/etc/foo.properties

Comment: http://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OSGi you need to use import|export of packages to allow loading resources from other bundles. Put the properties file into a package which you export from that bundle. And then from the other bundle, you import that package. You should then be able to load the resource from classpath.

Comment: That was it. I was actually resolving dependency issues in fuse by exporting some random packages in export section of main project.